# How to use W3C SVG test suite?

Tags: testing, svg, w3c

I wrote a script which tests several rasterization programs, by using the [official W3C SVG test suite](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/WG/wiki/Test_Suite_Overview) and comparing the rasterized png with the expected pngs pixel by pixel.

The problem is, with v. 1.1 first edition (2011) and v. tiny 1.2 (2008) test suites, in a lot of images the vectors doesn't match with the expected png, because the revision number is not the same, making a lot of false-positives (more than 90%), [like this one](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/Test/20110816/harness/htmlSVGWeb/coords-trans-14-f.html).

However it's ok with the v. 1.1 first edition test suite.

I could trunk the png to remove the area with the revision number, but it's a really derpy solution.

So by which png should I compare the rasterized vectors ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no non-derpy solution to this problem, for a few reasons. The test images from this time were never meant to be ref-tests (that is, they are not pixel-by-pixel matches). Also, some of the tests that appear in the later test suites were not accepted as legitimate tests, so the revision numbers were not updated.

The later [SVG 1.1 2nd edition test suite](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/Test/20110816/harness/htmlObjectApproved/index.html) should be considered canonical, but even that contains some revision-mark errors, like [coords-trans-06-t](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/Test/20110816/harness/htmlObjectApproved/coords-trans-06-t.html).

This is actually an issue for the SVG WG to resolve, and I'll raise it with them. The revision numbers in all approved tests should match the PNG references, and we can revise the tests so that the revision numbers match.

Answer (score 1):

In the future we'll be converting these tests (and writing new ones) for SVG 2 as reftests and scripted tests in the [web-platform-tests](https://github.com/w3c/web-platform-tests) project.  The SVG 1.1 tests are at this point unmaintained.

If you really need up-to-date PNG reference images, you could regenerate them.  They are generated using [Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/)'s command line SVG to PNG conversion tool.  In the [SVG Working Group's old CVS repository](http://dev.w3.org/SVG/), there is script (`script/generate_reference_images.pl`) to do the conversions and a set of SVG files to use (`imagePatches/`) to convert for tests that we knew Batik didn't get right with the original markup.

I've zipped up SVG 1.1 Second Edition test suite sources and [put them here](http://mcc.id.au/temp/SVG-1.1F2-test-sources.zip) in case you want to try re-generating the images.

Comment: How to be sure that Batik is full w3c compliant if we don't have reference images to compare ?

Comment: I mean, `script/generate_reference_images.pl` uses Batik to generate images. So Batik rasterizer is approved by w3c?

Comment: At the time the test suite was developed, Batik was the most compliant implementation (and also was easy to script to generate PNGs). The Working Group determined whether a given test rendered correctly in Batik, and if not, created a substitute in the imagePatches/ directory as the one to render, that doesn't use the unimplemented/buggy feature.  So the final PNGs were reviewed by the Working Group.